For riverpod provider with arguments, does it matter, using which arguments we call a side effect function?
When we call ref.read(someProviderWithArgs.notifier).performSideEffect() , can we use any value of arguments to do that?
Example: Given a provider below with arguments, does it make a difference

If a provider is alive or not. Eg. ref.read(FetchProductsProvider(productId: null, clientId: null).notifier).updateProductStatus(pid, true) where FetchProductsProvider(productId: null, clientId: null) might have been disposed-off.
Will it make a network request if not alive and perform a side effect?
Provider is alive with other instances also alive?
ref.invalidate(providerWithSpecificArgs) line inside side effect method will take care of rebuilding that specific widget because it is being watched by widget where the request is performed?

In my case, I have many instances of this provider initiated, some get disposed off depending on what I'm doing on app. Whats the correct way to call a method in such case?
@riverpod
class FetchProducts extends _$FetchProducts {
  @override
  Future<List<Product>> build({
    required String? productId,
    required String? clientId,
  }) async {
    if (productId != null) {
      // Network request-1
    } else if (clientId != null && clientId != '') {
      // Network request-2
    }
    else {
      // Network request-3
    }
  }
  
  /// Method to update a field in given document
  Future<void> updateProductStatus(String pid, bool inProd) async {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String pdtRefId;

  /// Find out the document ID then update the document
  await db
    .collection('product')
    .where('pid', isEqualTo: pid)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> value) {
       pdtRefId = value.docs.first.id;
       final bool? selectPdtInProd = value.docs.first.data()["inProd"];
       if (pdtRefId.isNotEmpty && selectPdtInProd != inProd) {
         db.collection('product').doc(pdtRefId).update({"inProd": inProd});
       }
    });

    ref.invalidate(FetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: null));

    await future;
  }
}

Update:
While performing update side effect using method described above, I get an error 'Provider cannot depend on itself' if I use the same provider arguments which are being used in the widget watching this provider.
